# Algorithm to Calculate Possibilities with 3 Constants?

Tags: algorithm, math, permutation, combinatorics

i want to calculate how many possibilities they are to fit some random bottles inside a crate. I get three constants.

```
N = Count of Bottles
k = Count of Crates
K[num] = How many Bottles fit inside ONE Crate
```

Example:

```
N = 7; // 7 Bottles
k = 2; // 2 Crates
K1 = 3; // Crate 1 -> max 3 Bottles
K2 = 5; // Crate 2 -> max 5 Bottles

Above equals to 2 Possibilities:
1: First Crate 1 -> 3 bottles, Second crate -> 4 Bottles
2: First Crate -> 2 bottles, Second crate -> 5 Bottles
```

My Question is, what would be the correct formula to calulate the outcome in my example, the 2 Possibilities? How can i form a correct formula, so i get the right possibilities? Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: range of `n` and `k`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic programming to find T(n, k), that means "how many ways we can fill up to the kth crate with n bottles".

```
T(0, 0) = 1
T(n, 0) = 0
T(n, k) = sum{1<=i<=K[k], T(n-i, k-1)}
```

Here's an example implementation (using recursion, non-memoized) in Python:

```py
def T(n, k, K):
    if k==0: return n==0
    return sum(T(n-i, k-1, K) for i in xrange(1, K[k-1]+1))

print T(7, 2, [3, 5])
```

Comment: Good Answer Thanks! But is it possible to not make it recursive? And show the "possibilities", like crate 1:1, 2, 3 bottles  - crate 2: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 bottles.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for all of the nonnegative solutions to a linear equation of the form

```
x[1] + x[2] + . . . + x[k] = N
```

with `0 <= x[i] <= K[i]`

where `x[i]` is the number of bottles in crate `i`

I believe this is a case of the `Real Donut Shop Problem` in combinatorics. There is a similar question over on math SE.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223345/counting-donuts

Since you need to actually display the results, that should be enough information to implement the logic in a loop over all possible sets of X values that fit the equation.

For more information ont he mathematics involved, see https://arts-sciences.und.edu/math/_files/docs/courses/supp/math-408/math-408-notes-b.pdf

Comment: Your answer does not consider the max limit on each crate. If it was correct, the answer to the example would be: (7 + 2 - 1) C (7), which is 8, but because of limits here, answer is 2.

Comment: It absolutely does. The second line of my answer specifies `0 <= x[i] < K[i]` The OP specified `Ki` indicates the max number of bottles in a particular crate. As I stated, this is a *special* case of the general donut shop problem. It is much more involved than the simple case. Further, OP did not ask for the number of solutions, but rather an enumeration of them.

Comment: And how does your *solution* take care of this condition? At least explain the modification to the well known general solution of `Donut Shop Problem`

Comment: The linear equation is simply to restate the question in a way that the asker may be able to find more relvant information for finding solutions. The actual solution is merely a suggestion on how to utilize that equation in order to verify a particular solution, and then implementing that in a loop over potential candidate solutions. Again, the asker did not ask for the number of solutions as in the combinatorics question. He asked how to enumerate over them.

Comment: Sorry, but I still think your solution is unclear and not useful for the specific problem OP asked. Only if you could add some algorithm/ modification to your solution over standard result.

Comment: I have added an additional resource and specification that this is in fact a case of the *real* donut shop problem. If you have a more complete solution please post it. My intent was not to simply solve the problem for the asker, but rather provide a starting point from which to develop more specific questions as well as useful keywords for researching the problem more in depth.